# parsing xml file with repeat row

Tags: xml

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<PARAMETRAGE>
<TABLE name="PARAMETRAGE_GLOBALE">
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CODE_PARMETRE"><![CDATA[text]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="VALEUR"><![CDATA[n]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="CODE_PARMETRE"><![CDATA[text]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="VALEUR"><![CDATA[y]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</TABLE>
</PARAMETRAGE>
```

I want to parse it in object java.
---Edit--
I have tried this logic but doesn't give the desired result:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("CODE_PARMETRE : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("COLUMN").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Valeur : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("COLUMN").item(0).getTextContent());}}
```

thank you for help.

Comment: You may want to tag your post with Java as well to get more helpful views. XML is used in many languages. Also, what have you tried? You need to show that you have attempted something and the community can help you solve your issue, they do not provide answers without you doing your part. good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the XML into DOM `Document` works but you have to change the way how you iterate trough the result `Document`. It depends on your exact 'desired result' how to do it but one possible way is here:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("sample.xml"));
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    NodeList tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
    Node table = tables.item(0);
    NodeList tableNodes = table.getChildNodes();
    int rowNumber = 0;
    for(int tableNodeIndex = 0 ; tableNodeIndex < tableNodes.getLength() ; tableNodeIndex++) {
      if("ROW".equals(tableNodes.item(tableNodeIndex).getNodeName())){
        System.out.print("Row " + ++rowNumber + ":\t");
        NodeList rowNodes = tableNodes.item(tableNodeIndex).getChildNodes();
        for(int rowNodeIndex = 0 ; rowNodeIndex < rowNodes.getLength() ; rowNodeIndex++){
          if("COLUMN".equals(rowNodes.item(rowNodeIndex).getNodeName())){
            Node node = rowNodes.item(rowNodeIndex);
            System.out.print(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("NAME").getTextContent()+": "+node.getTextContent()+"\t");
          }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }
```

As you see you have to iterate all levels of the DOM tree and filter the type of the child nodes on every level.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.its works for me.thanks a lot.One another question please,is how to get the attribute of Table name="PARAMETRAGE_GLOBALE".

Comment: In my example the `Node table` represents the table. `table.getAttributes()` gives an `NamedNodeMap` object that represents its attributes. `table.getAttributes().getNamedItem("NAME")` gives a `Node` that represents the "NAME" attribute ...etc. Could you please accept the answer if find it useful?

Comment: @rbahadi There is a thick mark next to my answer. Please thick it, I will gain some points if you do it. :)